# Auto populate a field based on the value of the other field

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need a JavaScript that will let me auto-populate a text field based on another field which is a select list type.

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="attribute-16 even"><div id="edit-attributes-16-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-attributes-16">Position: <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
 <select id="edit-attributes-16" class="form-select required" name="attributes[16]"><option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option><option value="32">Content</option><option value="33">Footer</option></select>
</div> </div>

<div class="attribute-17 odd"><div id="edit-attributes-17-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-attributes-17">Anchor Text: <span class="form-required">*</span>: </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-text attribute" value="" size="60" id="edit-attributes-17" name="attributes[17]" maxlength="128">
</div> </div>
```

The former field's value will be automatically entered as the latter field's value. That's what I want to do here.

Comment: Nothing. I only have the html. I need the entire script. Probably just load it along the page that generates that form.

Comment: Do you expect that someone here on SO will code and provide a whole script to you? We all got our jobs an need to get paid to pay our bills. Please come up with a specific programmer question or hire a developer.

Comment: Well just help me get started. It's just one field so I only imagine what, 10, 20 lines of js code? But then again I'm a noob. Oh well...

Comment: As a starter, I created you a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7WHUq/ I explained what you needed to do in pseudo code like this : //declare a variable for your text holder (var holder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an event listener to your select field and populate its value to your text field. Your HTML is a little messy.. so I will just write the jquery in general. You can fiddle around with it.

you have to set this event listener as soon as the body is loaded. So on your HTML

```
<body onload="init()" id="stage" class="theme">
```

and on your javascript

```
function init() {
   $("#selectListID").on("change", function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#inputFieldID").val(value);
   };)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Requires jQuery, I don't think the OP is aware of this.

Comment: Ohh.. yeahh.. May be i should've mentioned that. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="edit-attributes-16">Position: <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<select id="edit-attributes-16" class="form-select required" name="attributes[16]" onchange="document.getElementById('attributes-16-text').innerHTML=document.getElementById('edit-attributes-16').value;">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option><option value="32">Content</option>
<option value="33">Footer</option>
</select>
<div id="attributes-16-text"> </div>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C7pnj/1/

The key is to use the **onchange event handler** to detect user actions.

I'd also recommend to avoid "-" in id attributes.

P.S.: as others have pointed out, the purpose of this forum is to help you, not do all the work for you.